# am learning google app script , this code is not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

//here i need to check the value in the spreadsheetcell if grater than 100 should set value high OR else should print value low. But am getting syntax error

```
function myFunction() {
  var myapp=SpreadsheetApp;
  var data= myapp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  for ( i=18 ; i<=22 ; i++) {
    var newdata=data.getRange(i,1).getValue();
    if (newdata=<100) {
      data.getRange(i, 2).setValue("High");
    } else {
      data.getRange(i, 2).setValue("Low");
    }
  }     
}
```

Comment: Welcome. What is the textual error message that you got?

Comment: data.getRange(i, 2).setValue("High"); //here getting syntax error

Comment: @pmkro it looks that you added the missing braces that were causing the syntax error.

Comment: braces are fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a sintax error on

```
if (newdata=<100) {
```

The correct syntax is

```
if (newdata<=100) {
```